# IntelliJ IDEA doesn't want to indent with tab

Tags: intellij-idea, indentation

I want to indent with tabs, so I checked "Use tab character" in settings. But when I open projects which were indented with tabs, IntelliJ IDEA still asks me if I want to convert the indenting to spaces or keep it that way. Also, it creates new classes with space indenting. How can I solve this?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your screenshot shows the settings for your `Default (1)` scheme. Those settings are not applied to your project automatically. It's not enough to just select it in the combobox. You need to import this scheme into your project.

Click `Manage...` and `Copy to Project`, and it should work as expected. This needs to be done for all your projects.

Also, make sure you're changing the **language-spefic** settings, so instead `Code Style` select `Code Style > Java` (or whatever language you are using). Those settings may override the default code styles.